# AngularJS ng-click toggling between functions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
<span ng-click="resetbyTask() || filterTask(task.id, $index)">{{ task.total }}</span>
```

I am trying to toggle between fucntions in a single `ng-click` so that the first click will run `filterTask()` and when clicked again it will run `resetbyTask`

Comment: Wont it be a good idea to have a toggle function and you manage calling the sub functions conditionaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
// controller

var called = false;

$scope.toggle = function (taskId, index) {
  if (called) { called = false; return $scope.resetbyTask(); }
  $scope.filterTask(taskId, index);
  called = true;
}
```

HTML :

```
<span ng-click="toggle(task.id, $index)">{{ task.total }}</span>
```