# Using ng-click to toggle between two functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the datepicker from bootstrap-UI for angular. I would like to toggle between two functions. now() and clear(). Is this possible inside Angular's ng-click?

http://plnkr.co/edit/aMcKwXOSQwgnGwfNN9yI?p=preview

The toggle has the `ng-click="today()"` I would like to add `clear()` to it, thanks.

Controller Code:

```
      $scope.today = function() {
      $scope.dt = new Date();
      };
      $scope.today();
      $scope.clear = function () {
         $scope.dt = null;
      };
```

Edit - I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936286/angularjs-ng-click-toggling-between-functions) answer but I would like to explore all options.

Comment: here is solution if it is ok i will add as  answer http://plnkr.co/edit/G4Tohfia9x2SjDQutrPj?p=preview

Comment: reply me if u r satisfied or not

Comment: As you said, I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936286/angularjs-ng-click-toggling-between-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `toggle()` function which will call the function you want based on a variable tracking the state. You can then simply use this function in your template as `ng-click="toggle()"`.

Something like this.

```
var toggled = false;
$scope.toggle = function() {
    if (toggled) {
        $scope.clear();
    } else {
        $scope.today();
    }
    toggled = !toggled;
};
```

A shorter version

```
var toggled;
$scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope[toggled ? "clear" : "today"]();
    toggled = !toggled;
};
```

But if `clear()` and `today()` are no longer called in the template I would suggest taking them out of `$scope`.